# Decorator Invoked Automatically

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am trying to understand the logic behind two versions of my script which has decorators used in it. In one of the script, the decorator is invoked automatically without being even called.

**Script 1:**

```
def outer_decorator(input_function):
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        print "Outer Decorator Called"
        output = input_function(*args, **kwargs)
        return output

    return decorator


class X:

    @outer_decorator
    def inner_decorator(input_function):
        def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
            output = input_function(*args, **kwargs)
            print "Inner Decorator Called"
            return output

        return decorator


    def z(self, a, b):
        """
        Function returns a - b
        """
        return a - b


x = X()
print(x.z(1, 2))
```

**Output**

> -1

So whenever I run Script 1, I am creating an object of `class X` and then calling function `z`. So, in this case, the inner decorator function is not being used anywhere and hence it is not invoked.

**Script 2:**

```
def outer_decorator(input_function):
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        print "Outer Decorator Called"
        output = input_function(*args, **kwargs)
        return output

    return decorator


class X:

    @outer_decorator
    def inner_decorator(input_function):
        def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
            output = input_function(*args, **kwargs)
            print "Inner Decorator Called"
            return output

        return decorator

    @inner_decorator
    def s(self, a, b):
        """
        Function return a + b
        """
        return a + b

    def z(self, a, b):
        """
        Function returns a - b
        """
        return a - b


x = X()
print(x.z(1, 2))
```

So now in the above Script I have introduces another `function s` which uses `@inner_decorator`. But I am still only invoking `function z` of `class x`. But when I run this script I get the following output.

> Outer Decorator Called
>   -1

So why is `@outer_decorator` called and is printing?
 Is it because the decorator used somewhere is processed by the interpreter?

Comment: Applying a decorator with `@` *calls* that decorator. So you're calling your decorated `inner_decorator` there…

Comment: calling `x.z()` should not invoke the decorator however `x.s()` will invoke it `function s` has been decorated.

Comment: Yes @Rohit. I am not invoking x.s() in my script but still, outer_decorator is called.

Comment: Oh that is happening because you are decorating a decorator, i will explain that in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the `outer_decorator` has been invoked is because of the fact that you are decorating a decorator itself.

```
def outer_decorator(input_function):
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        print "Outer Decorator Called"
        output = input_function(*args, **kwargs)
        return output

    return decorator


class X:

    @outer_decorator
    def inner_decorator(input_function):
        def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
            output = input_function(*args, **kwargs)
            print "Inner Decorator Called"
            return output

        return decorator
```

This expression `@outer_decorator` actually translates to `inner_decorator = outer_decorator(inner_decorator)`,so in your code though you have not explicitly called the function that you decorated with `inner_decorator` but the moment you decorated the `function s` with `inner_decorator` it actually called the decorated version of `inner_decorated` which in turn called the `decorator` function defined inside the `outer_decorator`.

I hope this makes the things clear.

Answer (score 2):

Script 1:

```
inner_decorator = outer_decorator(inner_decorator) # i.e. a function 
# object, no invocation
```

Script 2:
Here:

```
@outer_decorator
    def inner_decorator(input_function):
```

this gets invoked:

```
inner_decorator = outer_decorator(inner_decorator) # i.e. a function 
# object, no invocation
```

But,
here:

```
@inner_decorator
    def s(self, a, b):
```

this leads to:

```
s = inner_decorator(s) = outer_decorator(inner_decorator)(s) # causes 
# invocation of outer_decorator
```

Comment: The final flow of function invocation seems to simplify the flow to understand. Thanks to @Ketan